# Type Mismatch error In Parsing to Json Formate in java

Tags: java, json, list, parsing

Hello EveryOne !
                   I have a List object that i need to parse into Json type using gson1.1 jar but its is giving type mismatch error ..here is my code..

```
public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
    }

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     // convert your list to json
     String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(cartList);
     // print your generated json
     System.out.println("jsonCartList: " + jsonCartList);

     return jsonCartList;

        }
```

Plz Guys Help me Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` type of your method is `List<Product>`, which is a `List` of `Product` objects whereas you're returning `jsonCartList`, which is a `String`.

Hence, the **TypeMismatch** error.

To achieve what you want(to return the `JSON`), change the `return` type of your method. It should now be

```
public static String getCartList() {
```

Comment: Thnk you Sir for ur response but how to resolve this issue without affecting functionality

Comment: What is the functionality you want? Do you want to return the `List` or do you want to return the `JSON`? Both can't happen though.